# System of two coupled nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I would like to solve the following system of two coupled nonlinear ODEs

$$\begin{aligned} \dot x &= \frac yx\\ \dot y &= \left( \frac{1-x}{x} \right) y \end{aligned}$$

What I did was the following. From the 1st ODE, assuming $x \neq 0$, I got $y = x \dot x$ and, hence,

$$y = \frac 12 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \left(x^2  \right)$$

and, plugging into the 2nd ODE,

$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d t^2} \left(x^2  \right) = \left( \frac{1-x}{x} \right) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \left(x^2  \right)$$

which eventually yields the following nonlinear 2nd order ODE

$$x \ddot x + \dot x \left( \dot x + x - 1 \right) = 0$$

which [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%20x%27%27%20%2B%20%28x%27%29%5E2%20-%20%281-x%29%20x%27%20%3D%200) can solve. However, this looks messy. I am looking for cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the quotient of both equations you get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=1-x
$$
so that $y=C+x-\frac12x^2$ and then
$$
\dot x=\frac{C}x+1-\frac12x
$$
which can be solved as separable DE.

Comment: Much cleaner, indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify more straight forwardly
$$
\dot{y} = (1-x)\frac{y}{x} = (1-x)\dot{x}
$$
so we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(y - x + \frac{x^2}{2}\right) = 0
$$
or
$$
y - x + \frac{x^2}{2} = A
$$
then we have
$$
y = A + x - \frac{x^2}{2}
$$
you can solve from there - not pretty, but clearer.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. The other answer was posted a few seconds earlier, so I accepted that one.